# Create multiple front-ends hitting same data source

Tags: web, shared-hosting

I want to create and host 4-5 websites using the same database. The only difference between the sites will be:

1. branding (colours and header)
2. data will be filtered per website (through sql query) and
3. Each site will be on a separate domain (but can be hosted on same server)

My 1st thought was to use API / Rest model and provision five front-ends in their own sub-domain. But as sites can be hosted on same server (I'm assuming one hosting account which enables multiple sub-domains), I think I can simply connect all sites with connection string to same database, avoiding complexities of using REST.

Is this possible and would i run into database conflicts doing this?
If later, I wanted to add a mobile app client, then will I need to build out a rest interface anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do here depends a lot on your specific use case, expected load, preferred backend/edge technology, future plans, etc.

1. **Site domains and servers** - 

   The main point here is that you can host your domains/subdomains on the same or different servers. You simply need to update the DNS to point to the correct IP (update the subdomain's A record). 
   *Note*: If these sites are all public-facing, then I highly recommend using an edge/proxy server and even consider a load balancer, depending on expected number of visitors ([Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/), or [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/))
2. **Decoupled architecture is almost always preferred** - 

   I would definitely have an API/REST layer to abstract the database from the sites. This ensures that you establish a contract through which any clients can interact with the backend, including your mobile application. You also don't have to duplicate DB-specific code across the various clients. What if you decided to change your schema? Or even your database solution? Then all clients will be broken and your customers would be unhappy. *As a guiding principle, think: if I change any one thing in my architecture, how many other things will need to change as a result?* 
   In terms of scalability, this architecture will also allow you to easily spin up more instances of whatever it is you need (databases, REST service, etc) should the need arise.
3. **How do I build and deploy a REST API?**
   Re: #2, to set up a simple custom REST service running on Node.js (and express), this is a [good tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/node-js-and-express-tutorial-building-and-securing-restful-apis/). The example also walks through setting up and integrating with an in-memory MongoDB database.
4. **Database collisions?**
   If you follow the above steps, this should be a moot point. Node.js/express and the databases expose ways to configure connection pools if the defaults do not suffice. Again, this will depend on your needs - how many concurrent users you expect.

Comment: the 4-5 sites are for initial marketing purposes and the intention is to reduce these in favour of a single site once we get exposure.
With regards a decoupled architecture, I agree this would help with creating mobile apps. If the clients require user authentication / user updates / product bids etc, then will this require separate API's to be built for every type of call? Any schematics on how to build this would be helpful (I can only find simple examples on the web). Thanks